# My Scrapy Shell Commands Work but Output is Empty

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I tested codes in Scrapy Shell and works fine.

```py
fetch('https://www.livescores.com/?tz=3')
response.css('div.dh')
gununMaclari = response.css('div.dh')
gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.ih span.kh::text').get()
gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.jh span.kh::text').get()
```

These commands show me home and away teams. If i use `getall()` I can reach all data for both home and away.
But when I run below code, the output is empty. HAt is the problem I could not solve it. Could someone help me to find the problem? Thanks.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

class LivescoresTodayList(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'todayMatcheslist'
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/?tz=3')

    def parse(self, response):

        for gununMaclari in response.css('div.dh'):
            yield{
                'Home': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.ih span.kh::text').get(),
                'Away': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.jh span.kh::text').get()
            }

runnerTodayList = CrawlerRunner(settings = {
    "FEEDS": {
        "todayMatcheslist.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},
    },
})
runnerTodayList.crawl(LivescoresTodayList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#common-practices).

The spider itself is fine. If you're using `CrawlerRunner` you need to configure the logging and settings, and start the reactor.

**Example with CrawlerProcess:**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class LivescoresTodayList(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'todayMatcheslist'
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/?tz=3')

    def parse(self, response):
        for gununMaclari in response.css('div.dh'):
            yield{
                'Home': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.ih span.kh::text').get(),
                'Away': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.jh span.kh::text').get()
            }


process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "todayMatcheslist.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},
    },
})

process.crawl(LivescoresTodayList)
process.start()
```

**Example with CrawlerRunner:**

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import reactor


class LivescoresTodayList(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'todayMatcheslist'
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1'}

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.livescores.com/?tz=3')

    def parse(self, response):
        for gununMaclari in response.css('div.dh'):
            yield{
                'Home': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.ih span.kh::text').get(),
                'Away': gununMaclari.css('span.hh span.jh span.kh::text').get()
            }


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runnerTodayList = CrawlerRunner(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "todayMatcheslist.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},
    },
})
d = runnerTodayList.crawl(LivescoresTodayList)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your are my hero :) One more question how can i provide to save json file to a spesific location?  I use this structure and it saves to main folder. For example i want my file to save inside a spesific folder. How can i do this? thanks Today.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},

Comment: You welcome. To save the JSON file in any location use the prefix `file:///`, e.g.: `r"file:///c:\users\user\Desktop\Today.json": {"format": "json", "overwrite": True},`.